# 企業アカウントでリリースしたアプリの情報（バージョンなど）が取得できない

Tags: app-store

お世話になります。

AppStoreにリリース済みのアプリのバージョンの取得方法に関してご質問をさせてください。
以下のURLにPOSTを行うことでリリースされているアプリの情報が取得できるとのことですが、企業アカウントでリリースしたアプリでは情報が取得できません。（具体的には、以下のレスポンスがかえってきます。）

【URL】

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=[AppID]
```

【レスポンス】

```
{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}
```

個人アカウントでリリースしているアプリはデータが取得されるのですが、企業アカウントでリリースしたアプリでは取得できないのでしょうか？

お手数をお掛け致しますが、ご回答を宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

リリース国を日本だけにしていると取れないようです。（アメリカを外したから。。。？）
以下のように、国コードを追加したら取得できました。

```
https://itunes.apple.com/[国コード]/lookup?id=[AppID]
```